# Did Antoine de Saint-Exupery have any offspring?

Tags: france, literature, family, persona

Looking through the [wikipedia > Antoine de Saint-Exupery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_de_Saint-Exup%C3%A9ry), I see he had a number of partners, one of them was [Consuelo de Saint Exupéry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consuelo_de_Saint_Exup%C3%A9ry) (the character who probably inspired the rose in *The Little Prince*). Consuelo had a child but with another French man (namely, Jean de [Vogüé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famille_de_Vog%C3%BC%C3%A9)).

Overall, by absence of obvious mention, it looks to me like Antoine de Saint-Exupery never had offspring. Does it seem accurate to you?

Comment: [Descendants](https://www.airspacemag.com/history-of-flight/fishing-for-saint-ex-2119101/) are mentioned in this Air&Space magazine article, but I think the word is being used imprecisely.  I mention it here in case it assists someone else's research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is no evidence that Antoine de Saint-Exupéry had any children either with his wife, his first fiancée or any of his mistresses.** His only blood-heirs are the descendants of his youngest sister.

---

According to both the Antoine de Saint-Exupéry site representing *[La Succession Saint Exupéry – d’Agay](https://www.antoinedesaintexupery.com/)* and the 1994 [Stacy Schiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacy_Schiff) biography *[Saint-Exupéry](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Saint_Exup%C3%A9ry.html?id=o5cbAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)*, he did not have any children even though he had often expressed a desire to start a family.

Antoine de Saint-Exupéry's [marriage](https://www.antoinedesaintexupery.com/la-genealogie/) (1931 - 1944) to [Consuelo Suncín](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consuelo_de_Saint_Exup%C3%A9ry) was childless. Earlier, in 1923, he had been engaged to [Louise Lévêque de Vilmorin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louise_L%C3%A9v%C3%AAque_de_Vilmorin) but she had second thoughts; her mother was opposed, Saint-Exupéry was struggling for work (she had refused to be engaged to a pilot as it was too dangerous) and

> She was neither the first nor the last woman to remark that he was
> impossible to please: “Nothing satisfies Antoine; nothing is perfect;
> his demands are not limited by reason. He searches out gray areas and
> misunderstandings.”

*Source: Stacy Schiff, Saint-Exupéry: a Biography (1994), chapter 6*

By the mid 1920s, Saint-Exupéry

> More and more often ... expressed a desire to marry. He was sick of
> “this perpetually temporary life”; he wanted children, “beaucoup de
> petits Antoines.” However, he lamented, he had only met one woman to
> whom he had  been tempted to make this commitment.

*Source: Schiff, chapter 7*

That 'one woman' was Louise de Vilmorin.

Saint-Exupéry had a number of affairs, most notably with [Hélène (Nelly) de Vogüé](https://www.antoinedesaintexupery.com/personne/nelly-de-vogue-1908-2003/), who later wrote a biography of him under pseudonym Pierre Chevrier. She was the wife of the industrialist [Jean de Vogüé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_de_Vog%C3%BC%C3%A9). There is no evidence of any children from any of these affairs. Given that Saint-Exupéry died without a will and that [his estate has been in dispute](http://www.lalettredulibraire.com/2014/03/26/Les-gros-sous-de-la-succession-de-Saint-%C3%89xup%C3%A9ry), it is highly likely that any direct descendants would have come forward (assuming, of course, the individual or individuals concerned were aware of their parentage).

As it is, Saint-Exupéry's only blood heirs are the children (and their children) of his youngest sister, [Gabrielle de Saint-Exupéry and her husband, Pierre d'Agay](https://www.antoinedesaintexupery.com/la-genealogie/). None of Antoine de Saint-Exupéry's three other siblings had children; his brother died at 15 while his two other sisters were childless.